# ZlibDecompressor throws incorrect header check exception

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, zip, zlib

I'm using ZlibDecompressor in Hadoop, but I'm getting incorrect header check exception.

This is how I instantiate it

```
ZlibDecompressor inflater = new ZlibDecompressor(ZlibDecompressor.CompressionHeader.DEFAULT_HEADER,1024);
inflater.setInput(bytesCompressed, 0, bytesCompressed.length);
```

And here is how I use it for decompression

```
inflater.decompress(bytesDecompressedBuffer,0,bufferSizeInBytes);
```

I'm using Hadoop 0.20.2.

What could be the problem and how to solve it?

Thanks

d31efcf42e83e76d3df76d38db5d3c141f76135e7417de41d44dc50b507a07b03a07a03ad40f75db7f00038d7df02177db9dbbd01f02e35ef7eb60f6f77dfaebde3a0b7f75036d41dc3dc00c4e40136e3b044e83ec5d35f01044f050841011000c0df4d3ae40ec1079078101f02dfcd40dfbef9df5ec4db8e45d37d85102d350b8001d79f7de8303ce7a045efdd75e35dfc03b036f3c0f5e43034d78dfadb9e7ad7d0750c10c30bce7a103d04ef4000dbde01dfdf7a0c20b907df7def9d80137ef8

Comment: Why is there an odd number of hex digits?  Please verify your hex dump against the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem reported is that there is no valid zlib header in the first two bytes.  The problem with the data is that it does not appear to have any deflate-compressed data anywhere in it, regardless of whether such data could be zlib wrapped, gzip wrapped, or raw.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I had added the compressed content.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'll accept it. I have just found out that the problem is that different format of data was provided, but thanks for your effort.